# Is it a lexers job to rearrange tokens?

Tags: parsing, data-structures, lexer

I am writing a parser for a custom file format constituted of an undetermined number of data structures spanning over multiple lines. The lines constituting each individual structure are garanteed to be contiguous, but can appear in any order. In order to be able to assemble the structure, the offset of the data in the structure on each line is written at the begginning of said line.

I wrote a lexer that produces 3 types of tokens : `data_offset`, `data`, `end_of_line`. But that means it is now up to my parser to discard `data_offset` and `end_of_line` tokens, and rearrange the lines, which I feel like is not appropriate.

Should I instead write a lexer that produce only `structure` tokens, representing the structures stripped of the offset and EOL and reassembled into the right order?

Edit:

If anyone happens to stumble upon this post, What I ended up doing is a classic lexer/parser which simply tokenize file and builds an AST, then I implemented an "analyser" that can work on the parsed data, rearrange it etc... "Every man to his trade"

Comment: Not everything has to be shoehorned into your lexer and parser. Patterns and constructs are there to serve your application. Not everything has to fit the pattern. Your parser just needs to make sure that you have all three tokens in the correct order. There's another stage beyond that which actually *consumes* the stream. That's where you'd discard whatever is not necessary.

Comment: Rearranging tokens or otherwise converting the AST from one form into another would be the job of the code generation/transformer part of a compiler, not done at the lexer/parser stage.